# Autolayout Imageview over imageview

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I have a Imageview-1(bat) having Full view

I need to add an imageview-2(txt BAS) over it using Storyboard

But my imageview-2 should be manage according to imageview-1, so show perfectly over different screen

[image]
NOTE: want to achieve using autolayout only.

Comment: According to my understanding of your question , you can achieve this by adding imageview1 centre constraint in respect to imageview2, let me know if I understood the question wrong.

Comment: it causes my BAS image shrink

Comment: hmm why there is no relation between imageview1 and imageview2 other then centre constraint , please check the content hugging priority for BAS image

Comment: Why won't you overlay **Bas** image over the Bat image so that they collaboratively make single image and now you can show it anyhow.

Comment: BAS image can be change with different logo like SS / BDM etc

Comment: @ShivamGaur hugging priory ? how do I made change in it

Comment: @9to5ios - edit your question and add your source images (the "bat" plus one or two "logo" images), so we can see the relationship between them.

Comment: @9to5ios go through this link - https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-content-hugging-and-content-compression-resistance-priorities-476fb5828ef for hugging priorities , if you want to work more on AutoLayout.